# Holes in polygons causes triangulation failure in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, triangulation

I have holed (and un-holed) contours that I try to extrude using Three.js, but the console outputs:

> Warning, unable to triangulate polygon!

and the produced shape is distorted:

[image]

And this is the original 2D shape:

[image]

The code is at http://jsbin.com/odufih/1/edit. Press "Run Javascript".

The polygons are ordered in `exPolygons` array, of which each member is a `exPolygon` object which has members `outer` (array of points) and `holes` (array of arrays of points) like this:

```
var expolygons = [
  {
    "outer": [point1,point2,point3], 
    "holes": [ [point1,point2,point3], [point1,point2,point3] ] 
  },
  { 
    "outer": [point1,point2,point3], 
    "holes": [ [point1,point2,point3], [point1,point2,point3] ] 
  },
  {
    "outer": [point1,point2,point3], 
    "holes": [ [point1,point2,point3], [point1,point2,point3] ] 
  } 
];
```

This is the actual exPolygons array:

```
var polys = [{"outer":[{"X":103.181,"Y":220.799},{"X":104.364,"Y":190.337},{"X":99.849,"Y":182.369},{"X":104.803,"Y":183.405},{"X":105.069,"Y":164.693},{"X":101.856,"Y":144.889},{"X":96.602,"Y":131.47},{"X":94.137,"Y":128.41},{"X":87.938,"Y":126.121},{"X":68.853,"Y":124.712},{"X":55.191,"Y":137.809},{"X":54.012,"Y":135.274},{"X":57.142,"Y":133.283},{"X":55.261,"Y":131.519},{"X":49.807,"Y":133.03},{"X":48.27,"Y":137.16},{"X":48.762,"Y":142.672},{"X":47.331,"Y":146.85},{"X":44.672,"Y":148.789},{"X":45.573,"Y":135.814},{"X":43.345,"Y":140.126},{"X":42.719,"Y":137.016},{"X":36.671,"Y":141.24},{"X":33.291,"Y":130.355},{"X":37.363,"Y":127.208},{"X":36.772,"Y":122.604},{"X":39.952,"Y":125.467},{"X":42.663,"Y":124.482},{"X":44.19,"Y":120.736},{"X":43.192,"Y":117.816},{"X":36.355,"Y":119.368},{"X":34.878,"Y":115.119},{"X":38.146,"Y":113.954},{"X":35.52,"Y":109.941},{"X":36.896,"Y":107.535},{"X":40.517,"Y":109.3},{"X":48.975,"Y":99.851},{"X":54.198,"Y":97.87},{"X":55.123,"Y":96.323},{"X":53.293,"Y":92.238},{"X":47.891,"Y":91.602},{"X":44.017,"Y":97.261},{"X":43.072,"Y":95.066},{"X":44.522,"Y":90.935},{"X":44.008,"Y":88.647},{"X":40.073,"Y":88.1},{"X":43.185,"Y":74.685},{"X":45.661,"Y":77.401},{"X":52.455,"Y":76.115},{"X":52.093,"Y":71.941},{"X":48.26,"Y":65.59},{"X":52.041,"Y":62.795},{"X":54.785,"Y":62.356},{"X":60.725,"Y":53.764},{"X":64.398,"Y":54.837},{"X":61.601,"Y":44.213},{"X":62.183,"Y":42.429},{"X":68.685,"Y":38.57},{"X":70.857,"Y":43.864},{"X":75.301,"Y":36.658},{"X":79.74,"Y":34.903},{"X":81.903,"Y":30.601},{"X":86.186,"Y":30.127},{"X":96.983,"Y":24.682},{"X":99.042,"Y":24.701},{"X":102.3,"Y":28.63},{"X":103.329,"Y":25.855},{"X":118.837,"Y":26.405},{"X":120.026,"Y":29.068},{"X":121.061,"Y":27.36},{"X":125.084,"Y":25.838},{"X":126.883,"Y":26.514},{"X":127.849,"Y":38.57},{"X":128.615,"Y":33.388},{"X":130.273,"Y":31.36},{"X":131.323,"Y":33.438},{"X":132.884,"Y":29.553},{"X":134.28,"Y":32.955},{"X":133.89,"Y":37.482},{"X":135.186,"Y":37.093},{"X":138.311,"Y":30.826},{"X":140.772,"Y":37.436},{"X":141.693,"Y":35.85},{"X":144.879,"Y":37.805},{"X":142.882,"Y":42.808},{"X":148.072,"Y":39.964},{"X":157.87,"Y":48.073},{"X":158.349,"Y":54.987},{"X":159.992,"Y":53.247},{"X":165.235,"Y":59.029},{"X":168.358,"Y":68.004},{"X":166.742,"Y":72.543},{"X":165.338,"Y":71.529},{"X":160.255,"Y":72.686},{"X":158.431,"Y":75.073},{"X":161.396,"Y":76.487},{"X":168.524,"Y":74.919},{"X":169.529,"Y":78.059},{"X":168.336,"Y":85.228},{"X":173.242,"Y":81.367},{"X":174.67,"Y":82.369},{"X":173.259,"Y":76.874},{"X":174.359,"Y":75.745},{"X":178.357,"Y":80.253},{"X":179.604,"Y":88.167},{"X":182.692,"Y":88.307},{"X":183.609,"Y":92.202},{"X":182.202,"Y":94.947},{"X":180.434,"Y":95.677},{"X":181.412,"Y":98.679},{"X":183.225,"Y":97.639},{"X":185.774,"Y":116.788},{"X":184.176,"Y":122.163},{"X":185.003,"Y":125.744},{"X":178.737,"Y":137.703},{"X":176.195,"Y":132.677},{"X":178.874,"Y":144.616},{"X":176.53,"Y":145.613},{"X":171.927,"Y":132.208},{"X":159.229,"Y":117.148},{"X":154.959,"Y":115.578},{"X":154.223,"Y":118.482},{"X":151.973,"Y":119.361},{"X":153.848,"Y":123.672},{"X":152.992,"Y":125.585},{"X":151.361,"Y":125.072},{"X":151.736,"Y":135.538},{"X":152.862,"Y":136.284},{"X":153.905,"Y":134.54},{"X":153.711,"Y":137.53},{"X":151.96,"Y":137.511},{"X":146.422,"Y":122.475},{"X":143.737,"Y":118.367},{"X":132.696,"Y":126.829},{"X":117.466,"Y":150.083},{"X":112.725,"Y":162.23},{"X":112.52,"Y":196.304},{"X":115.346,"Y":220.799}],"holes":[[{"X":149.952,"Y":51.338},{"X":150.825,"Y":47.383},{"X":149.554,"Y":48.757}],[{"X":69.191,"Y":54.204},{"X":68.924,"Y":49.128},{"X":67.899,"Y":48.266}],[{"X":117.109,"Y":140.339},{"X":125.864,"Y":116.268},{"X":126.352,"Y":110.58},{"X":122.683,"Y":117.966}],[{"X":104.36,"Y":136.75},{"X":100.006,"Y":83.235},{"X":97.063,"Y":84.608},{"X":95.913,"Y":95.243},{"X":93.732,"Y":101.053},{"X":95.356,"Y":116.686}],[{"X":45.664,"Y":128.24},{"X":48.032,"Y":126.672},{"X":47.016,"Y":123.901},{"X":44.185,"Y":126.829}],[{"X":172.795,"Y":126.642},{"X":172.545,"Y":123.761},{"X":167.545,"Y":118.809}],[{"X":107.355,"Y":55.057},{"X":107.018,"Y":52.308},{"X":106.193,"Y":52.924}],[{"X":179.526,"Y":124.933},{"X":180.705,"Y":124.515},{"X":178.907,"Y":123.02}],[{"X":53.288,"Y":123.566},{"X":59.22,"Y":121.336},{"X":78.45,"Y":119.193},{"X":70.689,"Y":115.628},{"X":62.414,"Y":114.594},{"X":53.318,"Y":118.598},{"X":52.339,"Y":122.518}],[{"X":85.362,"Y":120.083},{"X":86.531,"Y":119.917},{"X":78.853,"Y":106.531},{"X":71.625,"Y":97.485},{"X":71.301,"Y":98.877},{"X":64.513,"Y":98.961},{"X":67.077,"Y":108.022}],[{"X":149.92,"Y":118.838},{"X":150.14,"Y":114.686},{"X":148.165,"Y":115.206},{"X":148.026,"Y":117.129}],[{"X":134.804,"Y":118.44},{"X":140.042,"Y":114.261},{"X":141.194,"Y":111.614},{"X":140.626,"Y":109.57},{"X":136.364,"Y":113.732}],[{"X":180.366,"Y":116.489},{"X":181.073,"Y":115.652},{"X":179.356,"Y":113.954},{"X":178.754,"Y":115.154}],[{"X":90.309,"Y":115.534},{"X":79.772,"Y":93.054},{"X":85.146,"Y":109.227}],[{"X":182.402,"Y":113.665},{"X":182.443,"Y":110.685},{"X":181.359,"Y":111.614}],[{"X":55.341,"Y":111.837},{"X":57.863,"Y":110.873},{"X":60.011,"Y":106.122},{"X":53.019,"Y":111.614}],[{"X":165.02,"Y":111.614},{"X":165.861,"Y":110.999},{"X":164.028,"Y":110.999}],[{"X":130.927,"Y":111.506},{"X":134.03,"Y":106.264},{"X":132.577,"Y":105.091}],[{"X":144.754,"Y":110.413},{"X":147.103,"Y":108.35},{"X":142.043,"Y":106.954}],[{"X":63.015,"Y":109.3},{"X":64.361,"Y":108.284},{"X":62.673,"Y":107.573},{"X":61.917,"Y":108.622}],[{"X":109.357,"Y":106.986},{"X":113.698,"Y":100.241},{"X":115.484,"Y":92.472},{"X":112.667,"Y":84.929},{"X":109.008,"Y":81.867},{"X":107.649,"Y":102.006}],[{"X":54.854,"Y":106.986},{"X":57.571,"Y":102.662},{"X":56.336,"Y":102.669},{"X":54.054,"Y":106.186}],[{"X":179.811,"Y":105.113},{"X":181.698,"Y":103.895},{"X":181.434,"Y":102.679},{"X":178.454,"Y":102.679}],[{"X":108.201,"Y":159.955},{"X":113.362,"Y":134.854},{"X":115.184,"Y":111.846},{"X":114.144,"Y":107.699},{"X":112.611,"Y":109.222},{"X":109.523,"Y":119.341}],[{"X":88.282,"Y":100.121},{"X":90.571,"Y":89.911},{"X":89.545,"Y":85.085},{"X":85.997,"Y":85.742},{"X":86.185,"Y":93.779}],[{"X":77.239,"Y":98.371},{"X":74.257,"Y":90.532},{"X":68.27,"Y":88.13}],[{"X":59.163,"Y":94.781},{"X":61.287,"Y":92.082},{"X":59.71,"Y":88.948},{"X":54.89,"Y":87.878},{"X":55.847,"Y":91.156}],[{"X":156.428,"Y":94.218},{"X":158.058,"Y":92.011},{"X":157.383,"Y":90.475},{"X":153.958,"Y":92.285}],[{"X":171.563,"Y":92.566},{"X":173.544,"Y":88.952},{"X":172.799,"Y":88.055},{"X":170.49,"Y":91.299}],[{"X":77.032,"Y":89.283},{"X":75.208,"Y":84.541},{"X":69.734,"Y":77.597},{"X":68.922,"Y":79.777}],[{"X":119.637,"Y":88.115},{"X":120.304,"Y":77.135},{"X":119.264,"Y":72.438},{"X":117.388,"Y":73.992},{"X":117.516,"Y":80.792}],[{"X":142.69,"Y":85.445},{"X":144.136,"Y":81.354},{"X":143.001,"Y":80.859}],[{"X":148.866,"Y":85.224},{"X":153.643,"Y":80.839},{"X":149.794,"Y":81.881}],[{"X":165.286,"Y":85.199},{"X":164.7,"Y":83.746},{"X":160.512,"Y":81.803},{"X":160.192,"Y":82.909}],[{"X":130.502,"Y":84.798},{"X":132.592,"Y":78.84},{"X":131.36,"Y":78.336}],[{"X":62.515,"Y":84.688},{"X":63.7,"Y":82.176},{"X":60.188,"Y":74.465},{"X":54.168,"Y":78.902},{"X":56.52,"Y":81.653}],[{"X":48.19,"Y":81.653},{"X":51.148,"Y":79.669},{"X":47.538,"Y":77.053},{"X":45.324,"Y":79.736}],[{"X":84.601,"Y":80.65},{"X":87.17,"Y":79.387},{"X":88.897,"Y":74.98},{"X":85.458,"Y":75.507}],[{"X":76.947,"Y":79.839},{"X":76.473,"Y":77.849},{"X":73.85,"Y":76.163}],[{"X":96.853,"Y":79.315},{"X":98.44,"Y":77.997},{"X":97.359,"Y":77},{"X":95.923,"Y":78.708}],[{"X":66.177,"Y":75.689},{"X":67.546,"Y":73.526},{"X":63.281,"Y":72.581}],[{"X":130.539,"Y":73.142},{"X":131.294,"Y":68.99},{"X":130.02,"Y":64.963}],[{"X":65.017,"Y":61.368},{"X":64.345,"Y":59.693},{"X":61.299,"Y":58.5},{"X":60.496,"Y":59.851}],[{"X":135.018,"Y":100.857},{"X":137.266,"Y":99.498},{"X":136.611,"Y":98.542},{"X":133.988,"Y":100.292}]]},{"outer":[{"X":38.514,"Y":145.195},{"X":37.752,"Y":142.742},{"X":39.6,"Y":142.152}],"holes":[]},{"outer":[{"X":157.87,"Y":124.933},{"X":156.944,"Y":122.296},{"X":160.246,"Y":121.59}],"holes":[]},{"outer":[{"X":47.011,"Y":72.151},{"X":46.675,"Y":68.557},{"X":47.796,"Y":70.737}],"holes":[]},{"outer":[{"X":54.646,"Y":61.208},{"X":53.213,"Y":60.121},{"X":54.348,"Y":57.995},{"X":55.63,"Y":58.915}],"holes":[]}];
```

Then I convert `exPolygons` structure to Three.js shapes using as follow:

```
if (typeof(polys) != "undefined")
{
    var exPolygons = polys;
    var a, i, j, jlen, ilen, exPolygon, holes, outer, polygon, outer_shape, hole_shape;
    var alen = exPolygons.length;
    var shapes = new Array(alen);
    for (a = 0; a < alen; a++)
    {
      exPolygon = exPolygons[a];
      holes = exPolygon.holes;
      outer = exPolygon.outer;
      jlen = outer.length;
      if (jlen)      
      {
        for (j = 0; j < jlen; j++)
        {
          point = outer[j];
          point = new THREE.Vector2(point.X, point.Y); // convert Clipper point to THREE.Vector2
          outer[j] = point;
        }
        outer = new THREE.Shape(outer);
        ilen = holes.length;
        if (ilen)
        {
          for (i = 0; i < ilen; i++)
          {
            polygon = holes[i];
            for (j = 0, jlen = polygon.length; j < jlen; j++)
            {
              point = polygon[j];
              point = new THREE.Vector2(point.X, point.Y); // convert Clipper point to THREE.Vector2
              polygon[j] = point;
            }
            holes[i] = new THREE.Shape(polygon);
          }
          outer.holes = holes;
        }
        shapes[a] = outer;
      }
    }
   shapes = shapes.filter(function(){return true});
}
```

Then I make a basic extrusion:

```
var extrusionSettings = {
    amount: 20,
    bevelEnabled: true,
    bevelThickness: 0.7,
    bevelSize: 0.7,
    bevelSegments: 8,
    material: 0,
    extrudeMaterial: 1
};

var geometry1 = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shapes, extrusionSettings);
```

Any idea what causes this and **what are the exact requirements for extrudable polygons in Three.js triangulation?**

It has something to do with holes, because if I remove them at all, the triangulation goes without errors.

Comment: For the record, I've also seen those problems ( http://st.hjg.com.ar/mysis/mysis , type "Hello!", select "Lemon" font, and look at the exclamation point), I also see that message in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3386:

But fortunately there was already the tri2js triangulator calling function named triangulateShape2() in three.js, which was commented out (for unknown reason).

I downloaded https://code.google.com/r/remiturboult-poly2tri-js-2/source/browse/src/js/poly2tri.js and replaced in Three.js the line "triangulateShape: function ( contour, holes )" with "triangulateShape2: function ( contour, holes )" to disable the default triangulator.

Then enabled "triangulateShape2 : function( pts, holes )" by changing it to "triangulateShape : function( pts, holes )".

After that the polygon data triangulated exactly right and well! But of course it has also limitations regarding semi-adjacent duplicates, which are needed to handle in a way that doesn't break the geometry.

The faulty part was not my data or parser, but some odd bug in Three.js r58 default triangulator. When I chaged it to use poly2tri.js, the Tree image in the question triangulated and rendered correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to use **poly2tri** (or some other triangulation library) in your three.js project I would like to refer to a [three.js triangulation library (an adapter)](https://github.com/Wilt/three.js_triangulation) I made. The adapter allows connecting three other triangulation libraries seamlessly to your three.js project, one of them is `poly2tri`:

- [earcut](https://github.com/mapbox/earcut) - earcut triangulation library
- [poly2tri](https://github.com/r3mi/poly2tri.js) - poly2tri triangulation library
- [libtess](https://github.com/brendankenny/libtess.js/) - libtess tessellation library

All you need to do is include the `triangulation.js` file:

```
<script src="triangulation.js"></script>
```

And set the library of your choosing using the `setLibrary` method:

```
THREE.Triangulation.setLibrary('poly2tri');
```

Obviously you will need to embed of the `poly2tri` library itself.

**[Here you can see the triangulation result using the different libraries](https://rawgit.com/Wilt/three.js_triangulation/master/viewers/multiple.html?shape=tree.json)** for the first part of your tree.

Read more about the project **[here on GitHub](https://github.com/Wilt/three.js_triangulation)**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Three.js, but I'll bet anything it's a problem with coincident surfaces and direction of points being clockwise/counterclockwise.  Anyone who develops 3D rendering code from scratch has seen this sort of thing.  Even if the API you're using says it's smart enough to handle such  things, there could be a bug.

That long horizontal line running across near the top bother me - try to find the exact points in your array and see how they are related.  Syntax error?  Are these points from adjacent holes in the array?  Methinks there's a clue.

What happens if you change the order of the hole polygons?  I mean instead of hole #1, hole #2, ... , hole #N, try hole #N, hole #N-1, ... hole #1.   And then try reversing the points of any one hole.

OTOH, once upon a time I had a weird problem somewhat like that with POV-Ray, and it turned out to be a bad connection in the motherboard resulting in rare bit errors, a few out of every billion. The C++ compiler I used was built on that machine, and POV-Ray.  Things worked 99.99% of the time but some very specific weird problems followed.  But your image looks like a coincident surfaces bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! No orientation issue. Tested ccw and cw with counters and holes -> the identical result in every combination.

Comment: And I cannot find coincident surfaces. So filed a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional findings:

I got the same issue when converting an array of THREE.Vector2 points to a shape:

> three.js:25339 THREE.ShapeUtils: Unable to triangulate polygon! in triangulate()

I found a work-around to this by rounding all point coordinates to whole numbers.